# How to make unpaired data in python

Tags: python, pandas

My data is in this format

```
ID         input_1         input_2
1          'hello'         'greeting'
2          'algorithm'     'computer science'
.             .               .
.             .               .
```

The input_1 and input_2 can be viewed as the pair data, is there a way or a library in python to shuffle them to make input_1 and input_2 are not paired?

Comment: Can you explain more? Do you need shuffle only values in one column?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`numpy.random.permutation`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html):

```
df.input_1 = np.random.permutation(df.input_1)
print (df)
   ID      input_1             input_2
0   1  'algorithm'          'greeting'
1   2      'hello'  'computer science'
```

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try it.

Comment: How to make sure the two columns are totally not paired?

Comment: Are in columns duplicates?

Comment: Then use http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing this way `mask = (df1 ==df2).all(axis=1)` and then `print df1[mask]` - get all values which are same in both dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the random module - which funnily enough has a shuffle function!

random.shuffle(input_1)

(note that shuffle operates in place, yuck)

Answer (score 0):

read the data in as a dataframe and then process it using it index `df.ix[row_number,column_number]` and fetch what ever you want to fetch and process accordingly.